# Trying to export a document 8ft x 4ft from ArcMap and it keeps coming out blank

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.6

I have a simple MXD that I have the page size properties set to 8ft x 4ft, the intended output being a large wall poster of an orthophoto.  I have set my data frame to the 8ft x 4ft size, brought in the orthophoto mosaic layer, centered it on the area of interest, and that is all, no other layers.  I then went to Export Map in the File menu and choose a destination and a name, and ArcMap then exports, but the resulting output is a blank white document.

If I change the page size to a standard large format (ie. ARCH E) and no other changes, it comes out fine with the orthophoto visible, but changing to the custom page size of 8ftx4ft I always get a blank page, though at the right size.

I have done a raster clip of the mosaic, with the clipping boundaries set as a shapefile of the 8ft x 4ft area of interest and it gave me a proper TIFF, however does someone know why I am getting a blank 8ft x 4ft page when trying to just export to PDF like a regular map?

Comment: That sounds highly irregular.. does the PDF file size look like it has data in it? It may be a problem with your PDF viewer. What resolution, compression and quality is your PDF export using? Have you changed any of your print settings with the Advanced Settings Utility http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/get-started/administer/advanced-arcmap-settings-utility.htm?

Comment: Does your raster have overviews?  It may be worth deleting the overviews and recreating them.  When creating overviews, don't use the 'NEAREST' interpolation method.  Use the 'CUBIC' method.  I find that the 'NEAREST' option (at least in ArcMap 10.5.1) causes some odd results, including bits of imagery missing and sometimes COMPLETELY BLANK IMAGERY at some zoom levels.

Comment: PDF size was large, but tried a few viewers and all showed blank white content.  Compression was LZW and 300dpi.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I output the PDF as a standard sized 2ft x 4ft document, and then had the printer double the size when rendering to print.  Not ideal, but got the job done to the level of quality required.